# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System.ServiceModel.ClientBase and VS2010

Tags: c#, wcf

Every time I use a WCF Proxy client in VS 2010 I get at least 3 error messages:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
```

Do I need to concern myself with these?

Comment: Please provide messages and inner exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357436/wcf-many-many-many-first-chance-exceptions-being-thrown-then-crashes-app),

> First chance exceptions are not errors. These are usually exceptions
>   which will be caught. You should ignore them.

And here's a reference on [how to disable these exceptions](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/24).

Comment: OK ... but only if you say so :), by the way, I love John Saunders comment "You've started to look at how sausage is made, and you're not liking it very much." So accurate.

Comment: Haha very accurate. Hope his post was able to guide you comfortably.

Comment: Amusingly, this answer applies to dozens if not hundreds of questions on SO and elsewhere.  However, due to the way SO is structured it ends up being rewritten over and over, since this is not obviously a duplicate so people don't like to mark it and its kin as such. Anyway, thanks for the answer @Sam